# jquery possible to change value inside span

Tags: jquery

```
<span class="profit" data-formula="155" data-stmt="21" data-type="currency" id="formula_for_845" name="faw_det_attr_845[std]" outline="none" readonly="readonly" style="border:none" value="110">153</span>
```

How can I change the value inside this span - to match the 153 (it should not be "110").

```
elem.text(value);
```

That sets the text not the value inside...

Comment: `elem.attr( "value" , "153" )`. Or `elem.value("100")` maybe

Comment: it's elem.val("153") rather than elem.value()

Comment: @rupps this is span not input.

Comment: Firstly, don't use invalid attributes...

Comment: @guradio it doesn't matter, val() would just set the value attribute, regardless if it's an illegal attribute for the span tag

Comment: @rupps but span has no value attribute.

Comment: I know but val() creates it.

Comment: @rupps No it won't for `span` element

Comment: @Wolf yup, even though I totally agree with you its a bad practice, try in console: `$("<span/>").val(23).attr("value")`

Comment: @rupps Did you tried it? On which browser???

Comment: jquery 2.x + chrome but it's a jquery thing rather than the browser. maybe the attr doesnt show in the dom explorer because it's illegal, but is certainly created in the Dom node

Comment: @rupps It would set the DOM node property, ya that's correct!

Comment: yeah as correct as bad practice it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's valid for `span` to have `value` attribute, but you can try:

```
elem.val("110");
```

Or more complicated:

```
elem.attr( "value" , "153" );
```

According to comments `value` is not valid attribute for a `span`. So, you should use some `data-` attribute:

```
<span data-value="153">110</span>
```

And js:

```
$( "span" ).data( "value", "110" );
```

Comment: Not, it isn't valid attribute for span

Comment: i think its better to use `data-***` rather than `value`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
$('span').attr( "value", $(this).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use invalid attribute...

That's said, what you are looking for seems to be:

```
$('span').attr( "value" , function(){
    return $(this).text();
});
```